# Mothership Vortex Range?

Tags: starcraft-2

What is the range of the Mothership's Vortex ability? Can it be used across the map in the same way that mass-recall can? Or must I fly a mothership to the location of the battle to use it effectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mothership vortex has a range of 9 from the mothership and has a radius of 2.5. It cannot be used across the map as mass-recall can. You must fly a mothership to the location of the battle to use it.

[Source:Team Liquid](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Vortex)